# FlatList react-native not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In the constructor of my component I've got this code:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("@FitydeStore:weights", (err,result)=> {
  this.state.weightsList = result;
  }).then(() => {
  this.setState({refreshing: false});
});
```

in console.log I've got this:

```
{"key":"Mar 4th 18","weight":"88"}
```

Then I render my flat list like this:

```
_renderFlatList(){
  if(this.state.weightsList.length > 0){
    console.log(this.state.weightsList);
    return(
      <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
        data={this.state.weightsList}
        renderItem={
          (item) => <Text>{item.weight}{item.text}</Text>
        } 
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Full render of the component is like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.toolbar}>
        <Text style={styles.mainText}>
          Fityde
        </Text>
      </View>
      {this._renderTextInput()}
      {this._renderFlatList()}
      <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
        <Button style={styles.addButton}
          onPress={this._onPressLearnMore}
          title="Add new record"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and still, my flat list item isn't displayed.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it never enters in the condition `if(this.state.weightsList.length > 0)`

Check if your data well formatted like

```
[{"key":"Mar 4th 18","weight":"88"}];
```

Maybe you should parse your response:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("@FitydeStore:weights", (err,result)=> {
  this.state.weightsList = result;
  })
.then(res => {
  if (res.ok) { // or whatever condition you want to use
    return res.json();
  } else {    
    throw new Error();
  }
})
.then(parsedRes => {
  this.setState({refreshing: false});
})
```

If it is then in your flatlist change this:

```
renderItem={
 (item) => <Text>{item.weight}{item.text}</Text>
}
```

By:

```
renderItem={({ item } ) => (
  <Text>{item.weight}{item.key}</Text>
)}
```

Here is a [demo](https://snack.expo.io/rygpD6t_M)  of your code working on expo

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is setting state like this `this.state.weightsList = result;`
you must change this code with this.setState({weightsList : result});

For more information please check this : [react-native-state-managements](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html)

Answer (score 0):

This line is your error:

```
this.state.weightsList = result;
```

You can use this instead:

```
 this.setState({weightsList : result});
```

and also `this.state.weightsList` must be an array.
for example:

```
[{"key":"Mar 4th 18","weight":"88"}]
```